# YACC parsing operations with 0

Tags: yacc

I have a YACC program to calculate the addition, subtraction, etc of two numbers.

```
    %{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
%}
%token DIGIT
%%
L:A {printf("%d\n",$1); exit(0);}
 ;
A:A'+'B {$$=$1+$3;}
 |B {$$=$1;}
 ;
B:B'-'C {$$=$1-$3;}
 |C {$$=$1;}
 ;
C:C'*'D {$$=$1*$3;}
 |D {$$=$1;}
 ;
D:D'/'E {$$=$1/$3;}
 |E {$$=$1;}
 ;
E:'('A')' {$$=$2;}
 |DIGIT   
 ;
%%
yylex()
{
  int c;
  c=getchar();
  if(isdigit(c))
  {
    yylval=c-'0';
    return DIGIT;
  }
  return c;
}
yyerror(char *s)
{
 printf("\nError:%s\n",s);
}

int main()
{
 printf("Enter expression:");
 yyparse();

}
```

But I can't get my head around this part.

```
   c=getchar();
  if(isdigit(c))
  {
    yylval=c-'0';
    return DIGIT;
  }
  return c;
```

Why am I subtracting a 0? How exactly does the YACC parse my program, I can't understand EXACTLY how 3+5 is parsed with this logic and printed out. I know it matches A '+' B and finally they add it. But im still confused on why am I subtracting and returning DIGIT after subtracting and otherwise returning c.

Comment: A comment: With your grammar, subtraction will have higher precedence than addition, so 1+2-3 is parsed as 1+(2-3). Usually, addition and subtraction have the same priority, so 1+2-3 should be parsed as (1+2)-3, both being left-associative. The same for division and multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ASCII character set (and the EBCDIC character set, for that matter), the characters `0` to `9` are consecutive and in ascending order. That means that `0` and `4`, for example, are precisely four positions apart. So if `c` is a character known to be a digit, then `c-'0'` will be the integer value of that digit.

Comment: The value of c-'0' is being passed to yylval. Is this implicitly being passed to DIGIT, since DIGIT is declared as a token?

Comment: @PrasanthLouis not sure what you're asking there.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant was, how does my integer value enter into DIGIT? 
Or basically what is in DIGIT?

Comment: DIGIT is simply the token type which the function is telling Yacc to interpret the token as. (Non-digit tokens are simply being returned as their character value... this is a bit of a hack, and not normally the way Lex/Yacc are used.) `yylval` is the data (if any) contained in the token. All `+` tokens are the same, so no need to set `yylval`; but different digit tokens will have different values attached to them.

Comment: I would suggest that this is not the best example code to learn Lex/Yacc from.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to read as much as I could on yacc, but it didn't make sense. This helped a bunch.